# Heap corruption in an intrusive data structure example

Tags: c, data-structures, heap-memory

Here is a doubly linked list, with the node/link carrying the information needed in order to be stored in the list (intrusive):

`dlist.h`:

```
#ifndef DLIST_H
#define DLIST_H

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------

typedef struct Link
{
    struct Link* succ;
    struct Link* prev;
} Link;

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------

typedef struct List
{
    Link* first;
    Link* last;
} List;

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------

void init(List* lst)
{
    assert(lst);

    lst->first = 0;
    lst->last = 0;
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------

List* create()
{
    List* lst = (List*) malloc(sizeof(List*));

    init(lst);

    return lst;
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------

void push_back(List* lst, Link* l)
{
    assert(l);
    assert(lst);
    {
        Link* last = lst->last;

        if (last)
        {
            last->succ = l;
            l->prev = last;
        }
        else
        {
            lst->first = l;
            l->prev = 0;
        }

        lst->last = l;
        l->succ = 0;
    }
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------

void clear (List* lst)
{
    assert(lst);
    {
        Link* curr = lst->first;
        Link* next = 0;

        while (curr)
        {
            next = curr->succ;

            free(curr);

            curr = next;
        }

        lst->first = 0;
        lst->last = 0;
    }
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------

void destroy (List* lst)
{
    assert(lst);

    clear(lst);

    free(lst);
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------

typedef struct Name
{
    Link l;
    char* s;
} Name;

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------

Name* make_name(char* str)
{
    Name* n = (Name*) malloc(sizeof(Name*));
    n->s = str;

    return n;
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------

#endif
```

`main.c`:

```
#include <stdlib.h>     // malloc
#include <stdio.h>      // printf
#include <assert.h>     // assert


#ifdef __cplusplus  


#else  // compiling in C. 

int main ()
{
    List* lst = create();

    char* names[ ] = { "Giorikas", "Kostikas", "Foo", "Bar", "Gosho", "Pesho" };
    char* name;

    int i = 0;
    int size = 6;

    for (i; i < size; ++i)
    {
        push_back(lst, (Link*)(make_name(names[i])));

        name = ((Name*)(lst->last))->s;
        printf("Name: %s \n", name);
    }

    destroy(lst);

    getchar();

    return 0;
}

#endif
```

Stepping with the debugger I get the names printed and in function `clear()`, at the first attempt of freeing a link, I get two warnings and finally:

> _CrtIsValidHeapPointer(pUserData)

Note: after a bit of research I understand that: *"you'll receive heap corruption not immediately on rewrite occurs, but **on the next heap check**, which will be performed on any next memory allocation/deallocation."*. So, probably, what happens in `clear()`is the heap check that triggers the error.

Where is this heap corruption taking place?

Comment: Completely unrelated, but the names would make more sense as `succ`/`pred` or `next`/`prev`, not `succ`/`prev`.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but don't put function definitions (implementations) in header files. Instead only put the *declarations* of the functions in the header file, and put the definitions in a separate source file that you then build with.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY do you mean the cast?

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Learning to program C on an Amiga seeing casts like that was very common and not something I react over very much. It's simply a way to emulate inheritance in C.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY The `Name` structure have a `Link` member as its first member, so it's compatible.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I understand `Name` as a _"derived"_ class from the base class `Link`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY The `make_name` function just creates a `Name` structure object (well, it's *supposed* to) and makes it's `n` member point to the passed `char *`. Since the `Name` structure "inherits" the `Link` structure, a `Name*` can be used as a `Link*`, which is what the cast is about.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Ah I misunderstood `Link` and `Link*`. I do not seem to have enough sleep. Sorry Ziezi and Some programmer dude.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You make bad allocations. You need to allocate *objects* not pointer to, so:

```
List* lst = (List*) malloc(sizeof(List*));
```

should be

```
List* lst = (List*) malloc(sizeof(List));
```

and the same for `Name`at least. You can also remove the cast:

```
List* lst = malloc(sizeof(List));
```

-----EDIT----

and a much better idiom is:

```
List* lst = malloc(sizeof(*lst));
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the issue and for the allocation idiom!